# Is setting an id on views mandatory for all views like for instance a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android

Is setting an id on views mandatory for all views like for instance a ConstraintLayout ?

I have some views like constraint layouts I don't need using in kotlin code so is it necessary to set an id ?

Comment: No, it is not mandatory.

Comment: Setting an id to a view is only required if you want to reference that view in your code.